# Query data from previous day when month/year changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, getdate

In a SQL Server query, I am currently using the clause

```
WHERE
    DAY(trade_date) = DAY(GETDATE()) - 1 
    AND MONTH(trade_date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
    AND YEAR(trade_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

to query my data from the previous day.

It is working fine right now but my question is if, for example, on 8/1/2021, SQL Server will try to get data from 8/0/2021 or if it will know to get data from 7/31/2021.

If this query won't work what could I use instead? Thanks!

Comment: Have you not thought to just try it?

Comment: Well 'getdate' uses the current date so I can't try it unless it's the first of the month. I will have this query in an auto-refreshing Power BI report so I'd like to know if it will fail or not beforehand

Comment: `select Convert(datetime,'20210701')-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using proper **date comparison** logic - instead of breaking it down to day, month and year. Also, it is recommended to use proper date arithmetic functions like `DATEADD` instead of just `- 1` on your date values (never sure what that -1 stands for: minus one day? Week? Month? Hour?).

And lastly - I would also recommend using `SYSDATETIME()` instead of `GETDATE()` since the latter always returns a `DATETIME` datatype - which should be on its way out, and you should use `DATE` (if you don't need to time portion), or `DATETIME2(n)` (if you do need the time portion) since those are more efficient and have fewer limitations compared to `DATETIME`.

If your `trade_date` is a `DATE` column (as it probably should be), just use:

```
WHERE
    trade_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, SYSDATETIME())
```

and if it's not a `DATE` - just cast it to a date as needed:

```
WHERE
    CAST(trade_date AS DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE))
```

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the help! Obviously I'm newer to SQL haha

Comment: `datetime` to `date` is not great. ["Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea) Not really, better to use a half-open interval `WHERE trade_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE)) AND trade_date < CAST(SYSDATETIME() AS DATE))`